# How can I run Unbuntu on raspberry-pi 3 or 4 using only a single core?

Tags: grub2, raspberrypi, bootloader

I would like to use the Raspberry-Pi 3 or 4 to get a ballpark performance estimate for a 64bit-ARM embedded system that runs Linux but only has a single core. (I don't have the target system yet). I am using Ubuntu to get 64bit.

For this aim I would like to run the system using only one core.

I am not sure if Ubuntu uses u-Boot or Grub (/boot seems to use Grub), I have tried setting maxcpus=1 in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT (then update-grub) which didn't work.

The RasberryPi does not seem to have /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online either

so "echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[1-3]/online" cannot be used.

Am I missing something? Is there a different way to do this?

Thank you!

==== Update ====

Reading Ubuntu wiki page (link in noisefloor's answer),
It seems Ubuntu is using u-boot, which explains why the Grub change
didn't work.

The question is now how to pass "maxcpus=1" to Linux using u-Boot?

Answer (score 2):

Updated, based on modified question:

As far as I am aware, Uboot does not support, in contrast to GRUB, a boot parameter to set the numbers of CPUs used, see [Uboot Environment](https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/environment.html) and [Uboot env command](https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/cmd/env.html).

An alternative way could be to install Canonical's [Multipass](https://multipass.run/), which allows the quick and easy setup of virtual machines running Ubuntu. When [creating a Multipass instance](https://multipass.run/docs/linux-tutorial), the number of CPU cores to be used by Multipass can be set, defaults to one core only.

There will be a performance penalty running Ubuntu in a VM instead of directly on real hardware, but for trial purposes it is typically good enough.

---

original answered, based on the assumption that Ubuntu should be run on a single-core Raspberry Pi:

There is no Ubuntu release which support single core Raspberries, namely the Zero / Zero W and the 1B series. These have an ARM V6 CPU, which was never supported by Ubuntu. On the 2, 3 and 4 series as well as the Zero2 W, which have ARMv7 or ARMv8 CPUs, Ubuntu can be installed, see [Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) for further details.

Comment: thank you for raising this point. I am using Raspberry 3 and 4 - I have installed Ubuntu successfully, but it is using by default all cores. I want to use only one. I have edited my questions to better clarify this point.